# What ideal gas behavior is observed by a real gas that observes Boyle's law (at Boyle's temperature)?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

Boyle's temperature is a constant for a particular gas. At this temperature the real gas behaves ideally.

So, does the real gas only follow Boyle's law at this temperature, or are all the gas laws associated with ideal gas behavior applicable (or just Boyle's law as the temp is constant)?

Comment: Boyle temperature just means $pV=nRT_B$. It does not mean the gas behaves ideally. It is still approximation for a pressure range. The gas is not infinitely compressible.

Comment: Close to ideal I meant .

Comment: Being ideal has multiple aspects, fitting the ideal state equation is just one of them.

Comment: Such a gas behaves ideally in a particular context, if various aspects of its deviations from ideal behaviour mutually cancel, like in case of the Boyle law at not too high pressure.

Comment: I think I understood the gist of your unclear post, so I tried to edit it for clarity. I hope that's ok. You can revert to the original if you prefer.